# Azure container instances (ACI) deployment to virtual network fails (region: westeurope)

Tags: azure-virtual-network, azure-container-instances

my ACI deployment to a virtual network (target subnet is delegated to container instances) stopped working over the week-end with a strange error message:

> "The requested resource is not available in the location 'westeurope' at this moment. Please retry with a different resource request or in another location. Resource requested: '1' CPU '1.5' GB memory 'Linux' OS virtual network"

Here is the deployment script:

`az container create --resource-group $(resourceGroupName) --name $(containerName) --image $(image) --cpu 1 --memory 1 --registry-login-server $(registryServer) --registry-username $(registryUsername) --registry-password $(registryPassword) --ports $(port) --vnet $(vnet) --subnet $(subnet) --command-line "..."`

Also the manual deployment does not work - it allows me to select all the options accordingly but faily during the deployment with the above error message.

According to the docs at https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/container-instances/container-instances-region-availability deployment to virtual networks should work fine for ACIs in westeurope. Last Thursday it worked fine. Do you have any ideas? Many thanks in advance.

**Edit**: leaving out the `--vnet` and `--subnet` options makes the deployment work. But this cannot be the solution as I need the container instance deployed within the specified subnet.

Comment: It is working again at the moment - WITHOUT any change or interference from our side. The same deployment statement and procedure as stated above.

Is ACI within vnets considered to be production ready?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to reach out to Azure Support, this might be running out of capacity temporarily.

Also, have a look at creating Quota Request, asking for ACI quota in westeurope.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. Still, leaving out the --vnet and --subnet option makes the deployment work.. it makes me wonder if this is really a capacity problem then - what do you think?

Comment: a westeurepo issue with the private networking on ACI maybe ? people said that it was working before, its just not a coincidence that 2 issues were raised at the same time for the same resource type and the same region... that's my gut feeling.