# Azure container instances with VNET creation error

Tags: azure, subnet, azure-container-instances, vnet

I am attempting to create a Container Instances as a private network attached to an existing VNET and subnet. I managed to get this running yesterday, but doing updates or refreshing the image was painfully slow. I am consuming a private image on dockerhub.

Now when I attempt to create an ACI with the same VNET, subnet and image I get the error:

[The requested resource is not available in the location 'westeurope' at this moment. Please retry with a different resource request or in another location. Resource requested: '1' CPU '1.5' GB memory 'Linux' OS virtual network Click here for details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZjyq.png)

This is the command I am using when attempting creation via the CLI, though reassuringly (I think) I get the exact same error as via the portal.

// Fails

```
az container create 
    --resource-group xxx
    --cpu 2 
    --memory 3 
    --image xxx/xxx:latest 
    --ip-address Private 
    --location WestEurope 
    --name acixxxtest 
    --os-type Linux 
    --ports 2001 
    --protocol TCP 
    --registry-login-server index.docker.io 
    --registry-password xxx
    --registry-username xxx
    --restart-policy OnFailure 
    --subnet /subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/xxx/subnets/xxxx 
    --vnet /subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/xxx
```

I have tried setting up this exact same image with a public network and it completes fine, also updates and restarts work as expected.

// Works

```
az container create 
    --resource-group xxx
    --cpu 2 
    --memory 3 
    --image xxx/xxx:latest 
    --ip-address Public
    --location WestEurope 
    --name acixxxtest 
    --os-type Linux 
    --ports 2001 
    --protocol TCP 
    --registry-login-server index.docker.io 
    --registry-password xxx
    --registry-username xxx
    --restart-policy OnFailure
```

I have also had issues deleting the associated network profiles, but I have found a workaround for that as I see it is a known issue.

I have attempted this on two different subscriptions with the exact same results with varying different combinations of CPU/RAM etc. The common denominator appears to be adding any sort of VNET.

Using the link below I thought I was somehow maybe violating resource limit usages for the 'West Europe' location, but from what I can see I am within the bounds.

I should also mentioned I have tried this with the OOTB NGINX image and it fails also

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-region-availability

It would be much appreciated if anyone had any advice or feedback or shared a similar experience.

UPDATE:

Seems others are having the same issue:
[Azure container instances (ACI) deployment to virtual network fails (region: westeurope)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62152664/azure-container-instances-aci-deployment-to-virtual-network-fails-region-wes)

Answer (score 0):

I would reach out to MSFT with a support request asking for Quota on the ACI

I'm the one who responded here "[Azure container instances (ACI) deployment to virtual network fails (region: westeurope)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62152664/azure-container-instances-aci-deployment-to-virtual-network-fails-region-wes)"

Seems like a backend capacity issue on the westeurope region

Comment: Thanks man, I actually reached out to them earlier and was asked to post a question here?! I’ll give it until tomorrow and see what happening. Thanks again

Comment: ok, while normally we can help here on SO, this issue sounds like a capacity issue on their end.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was just an outage for my specific case where I needed to create an ACI with VNET. Unlucky me.

Attempted today and it created first time.